# Как взять первое и последнее значение из данных?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица. Этот диапазон я хочу разбить по index, и взять из него первое значение и последнее.

```
datetime,index

1633378385000,4
1633378451000,4
1633378505000,4
1633378582000,4
1633378652000,4
1633378717000,4
1633378782000,""
1633378848000,""
1633378913000,""
1633383874000,""
1633383940000,5
1633384007000,5
1633384011000,5
1633384205000,5
1633384266000,5
1633384340000,5
1633387730000,""
1633387750000,""
1633388380000,4
1633389103000,4
1633389181000,4
1633389247000,4
```

На выходе должно получиться

```
1633378385000,4
1633378717000,4
1633383940000,5
1633384340000,5
1633388380000,4
1633389247000,4
```

Думал сделать с помощью `first_value` - `last_value`, но оно смотрит по всей таблице, а мне нужно по кусочкам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение для MySQL версии 8+:

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, `index` <> LAG(`index`) OVER (ORDER BY `datetime`) newgroup
          FROM test ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *, COALESCE(SUM(newgroup) OVER (ORDER BY `datetime`), 0) groupnum
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT MIN(`datetime`) datetime_start,
       MAX(`datetime`) datetime_end,
       ANY_VALUE(`index`) `index`
FROM cte2
WHERE `index`
GROUP BY groupnum
ORDER BY 1;
```

или

```sql
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT *,
                COALESCE(LAG(`index`) OVER (ORDER BY `datetime`), '') previousindex,
                COALESCE(LEAD(`index`) OVER (ORDER BY `datetime`), '') nextindex 
         FROM test )
SELECT `datetime`, `index`
FROM cte
WHERE '' IN (previousindex, nextindex)
 AND `index` <> '' 
ORDER BY 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6104479de1664121d560f2629c3a3b5

PS. Задача стандартная, называется "Gaps and islands".

Comment: @Radzhab, добавил и второй вариант, не объединяющий. Но он требует наличия "пустых" записей между группами.